# Basic mysql question - how to search by time?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table where I have a column called 'timecreated' with a value of NOW() when it is inserted.

How can I write a MYSQL statement to get rows that were inserted from the past minute?

This is not working:

SELECT * 
FROM  `mytable` 
WHERE  `timecreated` >  '(NOW() - 60)'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: please post your table schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [DATE_SUB()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE timecreated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Or you can do the same as expression:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE timecreated > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND
 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can :

```
SELECT *  from mytable where timecreated > SUBTIME(NOW() , '01:00:00')
```

to get all row where timecreated >  now - 1 hours

or you can

```
SELECT * from mytable where timecreated > '2009-10-03 08:39:00')
```

if you want from a specific time.